# Row name possible?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, export-to-excel

Excel fumbler here. Is it possible to use a name for a row when the row number is variable (names are all located in column A)?

IE Putting together a formula to import values from a sheet. I want to reference "TotalRevenues" from a sheet but that name appears on $A$145 on one sheet and $A$162 on another. So is it possible to use "$D$TotalRevenues as a coordinate?

Comment: use VLOOKUP()..

Comment: Sorry, I mean $D$TotalRevenues, "A" has all the reference names.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is an `edit` button below your post. You can use it to improve your post at anytime. That's how I changed the `A` to `D`.

Answer (score 0):

Use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP("TotalRevenues",A:D,4,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, but you can use an '`INDEX/MATCH` Combo'.

To show what's in row '`TotalRevenues`' of column `D` use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH("TotalRevenues",$A:$A,0))
```